# poster/inforgaphic explaining what a rasberry pi is

Tags: software-development, printing

I am looking for a downloadable poster that can be printed on A4 that explains, in an exciting and engaging way, what a Raspberry Pi is and what its potential is. It is for a place where computers in general are not very widely used (Kenya) and where we are trying to get people excited about Raspberries. So it should be something simple which draws attention.

I tried searching for images on Google and raspberrypi.org but I found nothing useful unfortunately. If anyone would have a poster/info-graphic that might be suitable for this purpose, I'd be very grateful if you could share it :)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Could you please check for a more fitting tag, neither of the two works with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed the posters quickly I made them myself, perhaps these can be of use to someone else. So I've uploaded them here (p.m. me if you want to have the .xcf gimp files). (no warranties provided)

[what is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtToh.jpg)
 [image: ]]

[quick start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZek.jpg)
 [image: ]]